# Difficulty with blocking and react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am running into the issue where the URL is changing but the page is not when using react-router and redux. I have attempted the solutions from the docs involving location and using withRouter (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking), however, I believe the issue stems from the fact that I am trying to reload the same component and then use the params from the URL to make an API call that then re-renders the component with the retrieved values.

```
    <Route path="/video/:id" exact={true} component={VideoDisplay} />
```

and then from within the VideoDisplay component:

```
    <Link to={`/video/${props.id}`}>
```

I duplicated the component, which gets around the issue of trying to link to a route's own component:

```
    <Route path="/video/:id" exact={true} component={VideoDisplay} />
    <Route path="/video/test/:id" exact={true} component={VideoDisplayTwo} />

    <Link to={`/video/test/${props.id}`}>
    <Link to={`/video/${props.id}`}>
```

This works, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this if you're using `react-router-redux`. In `mapStateToProps` for the connected `VideoDisplay` component you get a second argument `ownProps` which contains the id from the route params. You pass this into the component as `id` or `videoId`. Then the component should automatically re-render if the id has changed. In short, there's no such thing as "reloading the same component" when you're using `react`, `redux`, `react-router`, and (!) `react-router-redux` properly.

Comment: Thanks, should have been using `react-router-redux`. However, what I ended up doing was passing `componentDidMount` to `componentWillRecieveProps` inside an `if` statement checking for changes to the path.